Bullets frequently spawning below the floor
I have a bulletSpawnPoint, and it is correctly rotating and moving with player, but the bullets (I've replaced them with sphere without collisions) are spawning under the floor with lower y coordinate. It happens most of the time; rarely a bullet spawns in the correct position and y coordinate.
Hierarchy of scene:

Sphere component:

Code of the Projectile Gun Component:
using UnityEngine;

public class ProjectileGun : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject bulletPrefab;
    public Transform bulletSpawnPoint;
    public float shootForce, upwardForce;
    public float timeBetweenShooting;
    public int magazineSize, bulletsPerTap;
    public bool allowButtonHold = true;

    private int bulletsLeft;
    private bool readyToShoot = true;

    void Start() {
        bulletsLeft = magazineSize;
        readyToShoot = true;
    }

    void Update() {
        HandleInput();
    }

    void HandleInput() {
        if (allowButtonHold && Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
            if (readyToShoot) Shoot();
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            if (readyToShoot) Shoot();
        }
    }

    void Shoot() {
        if (!readyToShoot || bulletsLeft <= 0) return;

        readyToShoot = false;

        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;

        Vector3 targetPoint;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) {
            targetPoint = hit.point;
        }
        else {
            targetPoint = ray.GetPoint(100);
        }

        Vector3 shootDirection = (targetPoint - bulletSpawnPoint.position).normalized;

        Vector3 fixedSpawnPosition = new Vector3(bulletSpawnPoint.position.x, bulletSpawnPoint.position.y, bulletSpawnPoint.position.z);
        GameObject currentBullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, fixedSpawnPosition, Quaternion.LookRotation(shootDirection));

        if (currentBullet.transform.position.y > 0) {
            Debug.Log("Correct spawn: " + currentBullet.transform.position);
        }else {
            Debug.LogError("Bad spawn: " + currentBullet.transform.position);
        }

        Rigidbody bulletRb = currentBullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        bulletRb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        bulletRb.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;

        bulletRb.AddForce(shootDirection * shootForce, ForceMode.Impulse);

        if (upwardForce != 0f) {
            bulletRb.AddForce(Vector3.up * upwardForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }

        bulletsLeft--;

        Invoke("ResetShot", timeBetweenShooting);
    }

    private void ResetShot() {
        readyToShoot = true;
    }
}

I tried to disconnect the bullet spawn point from the player, and for the first ~100 bullets it has the same problem:

But after firing a lot of sphere bullets it somehow fixes itself. If I move the spawn point back to the gun it doesn't fix itself with time.
Here's how it looks:

Logs:


I notice you have some debug logs set up to check the y coordinate where the bullet has spawned. Do those display "bad spawn" as expected, or does the bullet initially spawn in the right place according to the log, then get moved under the floor by the time we see it in the scene?

@DMGregory Yes, they display "bad spawn" as expected, bullets initialy spawns in different places, i will add screenshot with logs

Are you sure you do not have 2 times the script in your scene and one of them is spawning in the wrong positions?

@Zibelas  There is only 1 script, I checked and turned off all other objects, but still this 1 script spawns objects in different places, regardless of the speed of spwning

I created a new project, with the same script and hierarchy and the shooting works without problems, I have no idea what the problem is. I changed the scaling, but it had no effect(except that the spheres don't appear under the floor, but just below the spawn point.).
